# in redis-py , is redis.StrictRedis.pipe thread safe?

Tags: python-3.x, redis, redis-py

short question.
I'm using redis-py to set some keys on my redis server and I'm experiencing some weird behaviour.
I suspect it has something to do with the StrictRedis.pipe.
I have multiple threads pushing commands to the same pipe and after a while I run execute on this pipe and run all of its commands.
I wanted to know if the pipe is thread-safe? can I push commands from multiple threads without any synchronisation mechanism?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is not, according to [the documentation:](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py)

*"It is not safe to pass PubSub or Pipeline objects between threads."*

Therefore I assume you either need some sort of synchronisation mechanism. I have to admit I haven't tested any, but if I were to implement one I would try to go with a [Multithreaded queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue).

There may be a better way to do it, as I am not a python expert.

Hope this helps, though